# amazon s3 unable to open pdf file in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client

I uploaded a pdf to s3 and am using signed url. passing the amazonHeaders for content-disposition(I am geting back the response header for content-disposition). For this I put a patch in client.js in KNOX

```
var signature = auth.signQuery({
        amazonHeaders: options && options.headers,
        secret: this.secret,
        date: epoch,
        resource: resource,
        verb: (options && options.verb) || 'GET',
        contentType: options && options.contentType,
        token: this.token,
    });
```

and passing the options.headers

```
headers = "response-content-disposition:attachment; filename=#{file._id}"
```

But I am not able to open that in IE , I can open that in chrome.

I don't know if I really need content-disposition header at all. because when I try that from local host/expess nodejs server.it send the same response. And It is opening up automatically in IE.

[image: localhost]

this is the response from Amazon/S3

[image]

Comment: The problem is with only Pdf.I tried uploading PNG it is working fine..

Comment: What do you mean, you are "not able to open that in IE?"  What happens when you try? Nothing? Error? Browser window full of noise?

Comment: no error nothing.just..a gray window..

Comment: what version of Windows and IE are you using? What's your pdf reader (and its version)?

Comment: are you trying to embed the pdf in an iframe or object tag?

Answer (score 1):

The response headers in your screenshot are not showing a Content-Disposition header, so that part is not working - but I don't know if that's your problem with IE.

**If you do want to have `Content-Disposition: attachment`**

You do not need to modify knox (any more) to add custom response headers. You can do:

```
var headers = { 'response-content-disposition': 'attachment;filename=test.pdf'};
var expires = new Date(); expires.setYear(2020);
var url = client.signedUrl('/test.pdf', expires, { qs: headers });
```

This gave me an url like https://mikie-knox-test.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test.pdf?Expires=1594497470&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIW2ON37WUIIUJ2NA&Signature=fUQyOmYuPM2dEMPTY%2FRkssK0oxw%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3Dtest.pdf .

(I don't think you want `#{file._id}` in your code, that looks like a copy-pasting mistake, from a ruby source).